# Сделать кликабельную ссылку в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Такой код сделает из адреса `http://example.ru/usr/about` в тексте ссылку в таком виде `<a href="http://example.ru/usr/about">example</a>`. То есть ссылка ведет на правильный ресурс но описание формируется не правильно. Минусы (-) и, возможно, другие символы почему-то отбрасываются. Помогите сделать, чтобы ссылка получилась вида нужного вида

```
$ctext = preg_replace( '/(http)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\4</a>', $ctext );
```

Вот испытание кода, чтобы не быть голословным http://ideone.com/HGfnd

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = 'сайт http://apokalipsis-2012.ru/?search=%20&test ну и так http://ya.ru далее';
$link = preg_replace('/http(s)?:\/\/[^\s]+/', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $link);
echo $link;
```

Или без http:

```
$link = 'сайт http://apokalipsis-2012.ru/?search=%20&test ну и так http://ya.ru далее';
$link = preg_replace('/http(s)?:\/\/([^\s]+)/', '<a href="$0">$2</a>', $link);
echo $link;
```

**Добавлено**

```
$link = preg_replace('/http(s)?:\/\/([a-z0-9\-\.]+)[^\s]*/i', '<a href="$0">$2</a>', $link);
```

Comment: Но все равно не то. http://ideone.com/80ZnN . Видимая часть ссылки должна обрезаться из http://apokalipsis-2012.ru/?search=%20&test в отето http://apokalipsis-2012.ru

Comment: Добавлено к ответу.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ctext = preg_replace( '@(http)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?@i', '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\4</a>', $ctext );
```

Comment: Увы. Проверку не прошло. Результат тот же http://ideone.com/wL9ia